# tkinter.ttk.Progressbar manual alternative

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm wondering how I could re-create a progress bar without using tkinter.tkk.Progressbar, but as a subclass of tk.Canvas.

I have a step counter which increases towards a certain value.
Each time a certain function is called, the step counter increases by 1, and the progress bar increases by 1 bar.  Once it gets to 8 bars, it will then loop back to 1 bar.

I'm able to create the bars in individual frames and place them where required, however, I am completely lost on how to re-create the progress bar.

Comment: Can you show us what you've got?

Comment: Draw a rectangle. When the progress goes up, draw a longer rectangle.